# How can I create a Form in Web Page with giving User Option to add multiple fields and then Download PDF?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I looked through various answers for this but still cannot find a proper working solution. Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

1. User can add input fields, such as Page Title, Text inside Page. While everything is optional, More fields can be added, or removed. All depending option User.
2. Add Images, using Input Field. Again, User can click Add More Images and hence, using Onclick button, A new input field appears which can take input of Image.
3. After done adding the required content, User Can Download PDF.

Any Suggestions are welcome. I have spent way too much time with several PHP and JS Libraries but everything is Static, Can't generate Input Fields according to Users.

Comment: Please explain what you've tried, post your code as it is now, and link any Stackoverflow questions you've already tried.

Comment: Here's the first reference of giving user option to add more fields:
http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/

Here's the second reference for user input and downloading PDF which is done using Fpdf Library:
http://www.filedropper.com/pdf_6

Some of the Stackoverflow Questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php